# php 32bit date parsing for dates before 13Dec 1901

Tags: php, datetime, 32-bit

I was happily using [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on my development machine to parse dates some of which are in the 1800s, with an extreme example in the 1500s.

But my development machine is 64 bit and the server is 32 bit. On a 32 bit machine any date before Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC is out of range (see notes on strtotime).

I am happy to write some custom code for this, but thought I would ask if any of the php inbuilt functions will manage this. The dates are in ISO 8601 format.

For what it is worth the server is centos 5.4 with php 5.2.10

Comment: Aww... If it were PHP 5.3 you could use `DateTime::createFromFormat` which, I think, is the best solution for the problem. What format are your dates in?

Comment: 1901-12-12T05:00:00Z for example.

Comment: agreed with @Pekka.... any chance you can upgrade your PHP? 5.2 isn't supported any more, so you really should move to 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1901-12-12T05:00:00Z for example

I can't test it right now, but [`DateTime`'s constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) *may* be able to accept your format without needing `createFromFormat`. I can't really tell from the documentation.

Try

```
try {
    $date = new DateTime('1901-12-12T05:00:00Z');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Arggh! ".$e->getMessage();
    die();
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and see what happens, paying special attention to whether it understands the `Z` properly (i.e. makes it a UTC time).

`DateTime` uses 64 bit numbers internally on any system, and has no range limitations.

As said, from 5.3 on, you will be able to use [`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which can parse any date expressed by one of `date()`'s placeholders. This is the optimal way, because you force it to parse a specific pattern, instead of guessing it.

Comment: Thanks I have code working locally with this. Will give the big green tick if it works once deployed.