# Format date whose timestamp exceeds the int limit

Tags: php, date

So, we have the following code:

```
date("Y-m-d",time()+60*365*24*60*60);
```

The ideea is that I have to make a prognosis and I have the result in number of days which I have to add to the current date. The prognosis is for the year 2060 or past it...in an 64bit environment that works, but on 32bit not so much :)

any ideeas?

10x.

LE:

Ok so I've tried :

```
$date = new DateTime();
// for PHP 5.3
$date->add(new DateInterval('P20000D'));
// for PHP 5.2
$date->modify('+20000day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

and it works

Comment: There shouldn't be any limitation on the size of the number, large ints will simply overflow to floats. Have you tested whether `date` handles large numbers correctly? (Works for me, don't know if it wouldn't on a 32bit system.)

Comment: @deceze Just tried and I got `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in - on line 4`

Comment: @deceze: it wouldn't :) tested it on 64 and 32 bit platforms, on 64 works on 32 not :)

Comment: @arvin: on my 32bit it simply overflows, no fatal error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

http://www.infernodevelopment.com/forum/Thread-Solution-2038-PHP-Date-Bug-Y2-038K-UNIX-TIMESTAMP-BUG

```
<?php

// Specified date/time in your computer's time zone.
$date = new DateTime('9999-04-05');
echo $date->format('Y-M-j') ."";

// Specified date/time in the specified time zone.
$date = new DateTime('2040-09-08', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('n / j / Y') . "";

// INPUT UNIX TIMESTAMP as float or bigint from database
// Notice the result is in the UTC time zone.
$r = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM test_table");
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($r);

$date = new DateTime('@'.$obj->date); // a bigint(8) or FLOAT
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i: sP') ."";

// OR a constant greater than 2038:
$date = new DateTime('@2894354000'); // 2061-09-19 
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i: sP') ."";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is working on my 32bit system:

```
$date = new DateTime("2071-05-26");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

//i saw this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623647/php-32bit-date-parsing-for-dates-before-13dec-1901) question

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding full years/days/months, I suppose you could use simple arithmetic on them individually and then use `checkdate()` ([it claims to work up to year 32767](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)) to validate the result

```
$date = array('Y' => date('Y'), 'm' => date('n'), 'd' => date('j'));
// +60 years
$date['Y'] += 60;
if (checkdate($date['m'], $date['d'], $date['Y'])) {
   $fulldate = implode('-', $date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // A dirty hack
    function bigdate_to_string($t_64bit)
    {
        $t_base = strtotime('2038-01-01 00:00:00 +0000');
        $t_32bit = $t_64bit - $t_base;
        return date("Y", $t_32bit) + 68 . date("-m-d H:i:s", $t_32bit);
    }

    $t_64bit = 130 * 365 * 86400; // November 30, 2099 UTC
    echo bigdate_to_string($t_64bit) . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
susam@swift:~$ php datehack.php
2099-11-30 05:30:00
```

I am subtracting 68 years from the time and adding it back again while printing the formatted output.